# What does "overwhelming" mean in cryptography?

Tags: negligible

I found the term "overwhelming" when I study cryptography. 
According to the definition, we call $f$ **overwhelming** if $1-f$ is negligible. 
I already know the negligible function and its way to use but I don't understand why we consider the overwhelming function. 
Can someone teach me how to use it and some examples?

Comment: IIRC we don't always want to _guarantee_ that cryptosystems are functionally correct with probability 1 which is when we them to work with overwhelming probability / fail with negligible probability.

Comment: An example could be the correctness of decryption: in certain encryption schemes (e.g. most lattice based schemes) we have a negligible probability of decryption error, i.e., a ciphertext may not decrypt to the correct message. So we say the scheme decrypts correctly with "overwhelming"  probability. "Overwhelming" is essentially just a convenient way to say "with probability 1-f, for a negligible function f".

Comment: We want a system to work with overwhelming probability and fail with negligible probability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"With overwhelming probability" means that an event happens with probability at least $1−2^{Ω(n^\varepsilon)}$ for a constant $\varepsilon >0$.

Example: In a public key cryptosystem where $\mathcal{PK}$, $\mathcal{SK}$ and $\mathcal{R}$ are the spaces of public keys, secret keys, and sender randomness respectively, if $∆_{\mathcal{R}}$ denote the distribution on $\mathcal{R}$, then we require the usual correctness condition: for all $pk ∈ \mathcal{PK}$, all $sk ∈ \mathcal{SK}$, and $b ∈ \{0, 1\}$, we have $Dec_{sk}(Enc_{pk}(b; r)) = b$ with overwhelming probability over $r ← ∆_{\mathcal{R}}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do you define $\Omega(m)$ for a positive real number $m$? I see that you used it for $m:= n^{\epsilon}$. TIA!